# jQuery: Get last 'td' containing some text without using each

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table in below format,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Dynamic Text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dynamic Text2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dynamic Text3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the last `td` containing something other than just a `&nbsp;`. In the example markup shown this would be `Dynamic Text3`, but I will not know the specific text in advance. This is simply possible by running in a loop but, is there any way to do this without using `each`?

Comment: I don't think so, You need to use `.filter()` which will internally iterate through the elements

Comment: Have you tried the [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: `$('td:contains("Dynamic Text 3")')`

Comment: xpath selector? be aware that xpath is not supported by one and only one browser (guess 3 times which).

Comment: @LightStyle 2 he meant that text is going to be dynamic

Comment: If he doesn't know the text of that td then it is impossible to use the :contains selector, you have to loop through the elements to find the one you want.

Comment: If his text can match some regex or has some requirements no, otherwise it is impossible

Comment: As you can see from the bunch of "wrong" answers, you did not ask a clear question. You really need to work on asking questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work now

```
var td = $('table td:last');

function findTD() {
    if (!td.text().replace(/\u00a0/g, "").length) {
        if (td.parent().is(':not(:first)')) {
            td = td.parent().prev().find('td');
            return findTD();
        } else {
            return 'No text found!';
        }
    } else {
        return td.text();
    }
}

alert(findTD());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2uKB/3/)

Comment: Note that this crashes if every cell is empty.

Comment: @nnnnnn ah, I just noticed, the reason it crashes is because of `.prev()`

Comment: Yeah, endless recursion since you still get a jQuery object (but it's empty). Throwing in an `if (td.length===0)` test takes care of that.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, I changed it. Hope it works now. `if (td.length===0)` will work too, I was already editing it when you responded :D

Answer (score 6):

Update:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return !!$.trim($(this).text());
}).last().css('color', 'red');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rKda6/4/)

Comment: But isn't the (paraphrased) question "How do I find the last TD containing anything other than a lone `&nbsp;` or nothing?"

Comment: If using jquery then this answer looks much more sensible than the accepted answer. (the ´!!´ should not be needed, if you are a "number of characters" minimalist), +1

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** This doesn't cover OP needs, mis understood OP's question

Use :contains selector :

[http://jsfiddle.net/NkYZf/2](http://jsfiddle.net/NkYZf/2/)

```
var search = "Dynamic Text3";
$('table td:contains("'+search +'"):last').css('color','red');
```

Comment: @nnnnnn what do you mean? i don't get it

Comment: OP isn't searching specifically for "Dynamic Text3", the idea is to find the last non-empty cell (which in the example happens to be "Dynamic Text3").

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh sorry, now i understand the question

Comment: @epascarello - I thought it was clear, until I saw half a dozen answers that thought otherwise. (At which point naturally I assumed that _my_ interpretation was correct and the majority interpretation was wrong...)

Comment: I believe :empty will still select &nbsp;

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:contains`

```
var lastTd = $('td:contains("' + text + '"):last');
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't know what text to search for, just that it shouldn't be a lone `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible POJS solution

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Dynamic Text1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dynamic Text2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dynamic Text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, function (node) {
    if (node.tagName === "TD" && node.textContent.trim()) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }

    return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
}, false);

while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {}

console.log(treeWalker.currentNode !== document.body ? treeWalker.currentNode : null);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/r9nSF/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("td").filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == 'Dynamic Text3'; })
   .addClass("red");
```

Comment: But isn't the (paraphrased) question "How do I find the last TD containing anything other than a lone `&nbsp;` or nothing?"